# Mobile data connect to the internet but wifi does not work in release build

Tags: flutter, dart

It works on mobile data and wifi during debug but on release mode it does not work in the app. It shows an error of `Future.then must return a value of the returned future's type` in release mode

Answer (score 1):

Since you said it works in debug, but not in release:

Flutter sets the Internet Permission in the AndroidManifest automatically, but you have to set it yourself for the release version.

https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/networking

```
<manifest xmlns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

Add this to your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I have already done this. but does not work. It works fine with mobile data but not with the wifi

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error, you need to make sure that the then method on the Future object is returning the correct type of value.

Here is an example of how to fix this error:

```
Future<String> yourData() async {
 // Do some asynchronous work here
 return 'My data';
}

void main() {
 // This will work in debug mode
 getMyData().then((value) {
 print(value);
 });

 // This will throw an error in release mode
 yourData().then((value) {
  print(value as int); // Throw an error because the value is a String.
  });
}
```